# Google's 2-line blobstore upload example not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

I know there are a ton of blobstore questions, but I've dropped back to the most basic situation and I'm stuck!

In the long run, I'm using pure Django on Google App Engine with Google Cloud SQL and I'd like to upload a file to the Blobstore (but I can't upload a file).

I'm trying to run the following example from Google's Blobstore overview (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview)

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
```

but I get the following:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 270, in create_upload_url
gs_bucket_name=gs_bucket_name)
File "<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 334, in create_upload_url_async
_get_result_hook, lambda rpc: rpc.response.url())
File "<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 223, in _make_async_call
rpc = create_rpc()
File "<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 217, in create_rpc
return apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC('blobstore', deadline, callback)
File "<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 405, in __init__
self.__rpc = CreateRPC(service, stubmap)
File "<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 67, in CreateRPC
assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "blobstore"
```

I've dropped back to the most basic situation: Google App Engine SDK 1.7.6 (most current right now) and Python 2.7.2.

My path is this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
'<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6',
'<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/lib',
'<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/lib/yaml-3.10',
'<snip>/google_appengine_1.7.6/lib/django-1.4',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

Interestingly, if I try this with only the base GAE directory in the path, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

Could this indicate I have something misconfigured in the SDK?

I appreciate anything you can offer!

Comment: what's the exact command line you're using to cause this? Unless I'm missing something, all I see above is `python`. Assuming there's a dev_appserver invocation missing above, do you see different behavior if you use `old_dev_appserver.py` instead of `dev_appserver.py` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you are trying this from a plain python prompt.

You have some serious work ahead of you to get this to work (ie probably won't get it to work if your new to appengine, I have been using appengine since it came out and I wouldn't bother trying ;-).

You should be using the remote_api_shell if you want to use a python shell, and be connected to a server (dev or prod appengine) and your just exploring.

The code fragments in the docs you refer to are for code to be run by app engine app, either under the dev server or in production.

Comment: Tim,
Thank you. This is the kind of conceptual guidance I needed to get back on the right track. Now I'm using remote_api on my dev server to generate blobstore upload URLs.